# How to put specific hex characters in terminal to exploit the script

Tags: exploit, terminal

I try to exploit a simple vulnerability in the following code, but I'm not successful, because I can't put the specific characters in the terminal by hand. For e.g. if the application read a character from stdin and I will have to put a character in the terminal, I would use the ascii character of the specific hex code with which I want to overrite the 'check' variable. But if I convert a hex code to a ascii code in python or perl and I put it in the terminal by hand the check variable gets overritten with a other value (hex code). How I can overrite 'check'  correctly?

**Vulnerable Code:**

[Vulnerable code of root-me. org](https://www.root-me.org/local/cache-code/75aa923fe246e4668e75cc0be7376fab.txt)

Comment: What specific hex code are you working with?

Comment: Can you try to better explain what it is you are trying to do? Also, please specify what OS you are using as it may affect the answer.

Comment: I use Linux (Ubuntu) and my problem is that if I convert a hex code with python (print "\xbc" )  and copy it to the terminal the variable gets not overitten with exactly \xbc instead with \xbc\xc2